# websockify, noVNC in wrap mode

Tags: html, vnc, websockify

I need to convert a web page requiring viewing a X window from using the VncViewer applet to some HTML5 based VNC client. The worry is NSAPI will get desupported in the near future on browsers (mainly Chrome) that disables applet functions.

I looked at noVNC and websockify and got it to work. But, here is my problem: We still have some client on IE8 that does not support Canvas. For those clients which has Java enabled and won't be changing to a higher version of IE or Chrome, we still want them to keep running the applet version. By running websockify in the wrap mode, it seems I can no longer directly connect to the VNC server (not through websockify) to keep those applet clients functional.

e.g. My command to run websockify is:
run 5903 --wrap-mode=ignore -- vncserver -geometry 1024x768 :3

After this, I tried to use the regular VNCViewer client to connect to port 5903, and it's rejected. Only the websockified page can view the VNC window. If I change the 5903 to 5902, then I can use the regular VNCViewer client to view window at 5903, however the websockified page can't view it at 5902.

Is there a hope to keep concurrent connection to my VNC server available (websockify and regular connections)?

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting your VNC server normally (not using websockify wrap mode). Then run websockify normally to target the VNC port. The Java client should continue to target the regular VNC port. The noVNC client should connect to the websockify listen port (which will then connect to the VNC server target).

The problem with wrap mode is that the original port is "hidden" (moved to a random high port and accessible to localhost only) and only the websocket port is exposed. But you still need the regular VNC port to be accessible for the Java client.